# 89745928/apps: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount589745928/apps: no such file or directory

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker an when i run docker-compose build i get the title error. My question is what causes this problem?

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
       
       nginx:
         image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
         restart: on-failure
         volumes:
             - './apps/my-symfony-app/public:/usr/src/app'
             - './docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
         ports:
             - '80:80'
         depends_on:
             - php
       php:
         build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: .docker/php/Dockerfile
         volumes:
             - './apps/my-symfony-app/:/usr/src/app'
         restart: on-failure
         env_file:
             - .env
         user: 1000:1000
```

I have added this Dockerfile. Maybe it has to do with this file i am not sure.

```
FROM composer:2.0 as composer

FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install apcu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=1000:1000 apps/my-symfony-app /usr/src/app

RUN PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/app/vendor/bin:bin

RUN composer install --no-scripts --prefer-dist \
    && rm -rf "$(composer config cache-dir)" "$(composer config data-dir)"
```

Comment: That error should be read as "there isn't an `apps` subdirectory in the `build: { context: }` directory"; it should be associated with a `COPY` line in your Dockerfile (or perhaps `ADD`).

Comment: I have edited my post and posted the Dockerfile. What can i change here?